# How to prove weak sequential continuity of a continuous, bounded nonlinear mapping?

Tags: functional-analysis, nonlinear-analysis

Let $f \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ and $J$ a bounded, continuous and nonlinear mapping $J:H^1_0(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $|J(f)| \leq C\lVert f \rVert$ for some constant $C$ and $|J(f_n)-J(f)| \leq L \lVert f_n - f \lVert $. Is it possible to prove that $J$ is weakly sequentially lower  semicontinuous?

Comment: This holds for the norm itself. Is the norm weakly continuous?

Comment: The norm is convex and lower semicontinuous so it is also weakly sequentially lower semicontinuous

Comment: Yes, but is weak sequential **semi**-continuity enough to get weak sequential continuity?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to prove whether J is weakly sequentially lower semicontinuous. I will edit the question.

Comment: What about the negative of the norm? :P